# Can't see my build artifacts after Azure Pipeline finished

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a very simple pipeline yaml (see below)

What I am wanting is to build the projects in my solution, and retain the artifacts that get created so that I can release them to Azure in a separate release pipeline.

I recall doing something like this before, and when it worked I could see an option to view the build artifacts next to the successful build list item. However I see no such thing anymore.

What am I missing here?

Pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    zipAfterPublish: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add something like that (copy to artifact folder and publish):

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
       displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
       inputs:
       SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
       Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
       TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
       condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
       displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
       inputs:
       PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
       condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: This works, however in my case I forwent using a build task in place of a publish which seems to builds things anyway. This meant I didn't need the copyfiles step

Answer (score 3):

You have to publish your Build Artifact, use this task:

[image: Publish Artifact]

After that you can check your Artifacts under Summary:

[image: Artifact]

Comment: I tried adding a publishartifacts task at the end but all I got was: ##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Comment: Set Debug to true and check where your build is stored in the vm. 'Path to publish' in Publish Aritfact should be set to the same path in order to find artifacts to publish.

Comment: Thanks @point, this was the magic missing step for me.  For those adding this step, search in the pipeline tasks for  "Publish Build Artifact".  I was able to leave all the parameters as default.   After adding this to my Build Pipeline, my Release Pipeline was able to find the artifact for release under the drop folder using the ... button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add CopyFiles task and PublishBuildArtifacts task:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I based my answer by ms documentation ( all details are available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops ).

There are three tasks based on DotNetCoreCLI (restore, build and publish to correct dir) and last task that publish artifact to the feed.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)' # Update this to match your need

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Package
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish as artifact"
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
```